# WebDriver to close popup window after certain time

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have a `Selenium WebDriver` based test, which fill a form and send it for processing. During time period of processing a window is opened. Sometimes processing fails, but this window is not closed, so we can't get result. Purpose of this test is to get the result. I try to set a timeout for this window, so it should be closed after a predefined time (I set it to 10 seconds now.) by `WebDriver` and form should be resent. I use following code.

```
WebElement webElement;
try {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(sendButton).click();
    webElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("button-resultdown")));
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    webElement = null;
} finally {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
if (webElement == null) {
    driver.findElement(popUpClose).click();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
    driver.findElement(sendButton).click();
}
```

Popup window is not closed automatically after 10 seconds. I checked element locators, those are valid.

Comment: Do you get some error messages when `driver.findElement(popUpClose).click()`?

Comment: No, but I need to wait for some times before I click it. It is clickable, but I would like to wait before I click it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not make a note of the starting Window / Tab then just switch back to it?

```
String firstTab = driver.getWindowHandle();

//Do the click event

driver.switchTo().window(firstTab);
```

Comment: No, I can't, because it is an Ajax-like window, like this: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/Dynamic_AJAX_Modal_Popup/AajxModalpopup.jpg